# action bar sherlock in preference menu

Tags: java, android, android-layout, actionbarsherlock

I have a preference menu and i want it to be consistent with the app, so there must be an action bar in top like in the rest of the activities.

i tried it like this

```
public class Preferencemenu extends PreferenceActivity implements
    OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {
 .......


 class menuinflater extends BaseActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
          inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();


    }
}

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    dbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(getApplicationContext());

    Context ctx = getApplicationContext();
    TrainApplication ta = (TrainApplication) getApplication();

    actionbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionbar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    menuinflater menu = new menuinflater();
 .....
```

But ofcourse this doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extend from `SherlockPreferenceActivity`.